# Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler or it has been stopped

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Recently I strated working on Talend Bigdata. I have written some jobs that is getting executed properly. Data to process in every run is less than a gb but it's .gz file. Job is running succesful but I am facing the below error frequently although when reprocessing the job without any changes then it's success. Executor Memory and memory overhead is set as expected. GC collector is also set to G1GC.
Ane idea that can help me. Let me know if you some more information.

```
ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 131.116.127.73:45245 disassociated! Shutting down.

[ERROR]: org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus - Listener SQLListener threw an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLListener.onTaskEnd(SQLListener.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 16.0 in stage 7.1 (TID 30308, dl200dn42.ddc.teliasonera.net): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
[ERROR]: org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler - Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler or it has been stopped.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:580)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore - MemoryStore cleared
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager - BlockManager stopped
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster - BlockManagerMaster stopped
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn25.ddc.teliasonera.net:57604) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn25.ddc.teliasonera.net:57604) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn28.ddc.teliasonera.net:47162) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn42.ddc.teliasonera.net:58644) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn30.ddc.teliasonera.net:39768) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn28.ddc.teliasonera.net:47162) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn30.ddc.teliasonera.net:39768) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[WARN ]: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher - Message RemoteProcessDisconnected(dl200dn42.ddc.teliasonera.net:58644) dropped. RpcEnv already stopped.
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Successfully stopped SparkContext
[ERROR]: project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess - TalendJob: 'job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess' - Failed with exit code: 1.
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager - Shutdown hook called
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-afeaa959-3f23-4ffc-a5b4-eee7ed9838c0
[INFO ]: org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a5e1f6a5-7308-4441-ab95-1f1aab023c8a
[INFO ]: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator - Shutting down remote daemon.
[INFO ]: akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
[INFO ]: org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x162b8dd2d3c2595 closed
[INFO ]: org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
[INFO ]: CuratorFrameworkSingleton - Closing ZooKeeper client.
[ERROR]: project_cdl_tenant.job_000_sourcename_abcd_rawtobase_access_childload_0_1.job_000_sourcename_abcd_RawToBase_Access_ChildLoad - tRunJob_1 - Child job returns 1. It doesn't terminate normally.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/talend/6.4.1/jobserver_fin/agent/TalendJobServersFiles/repository/PROJECT_CDL_TENANT_job_000_sourcename_abcd_RawToBase_Access_ChildLoad_20180412_193439_A6T2O/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/talend/6.4.1/jobserver_fin/agent/TalendJobServersFiles/repository/PROJECT_CDL_TENANT_job_000_sourcename_abcd_RawToBase_Access_ChildLoad_20180412_193439_A6T2O/lib/talend-spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.8.1-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.8.1-with-hive.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.tHiveInput_1Process(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:2365)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.tAvroInput_1_InputFormatAvroProcess(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3718)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.run(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:4070)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.runJobInTOS(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3901)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.main(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3805)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.1 (TID 30301, dl200dn42.ddc.teliasonera.net): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/disk11/yarn/nm/usercache/prodfinbatch01/appcache/application_1523529055210_30771/blockmgr-23238b36-41e7-4192-9af1-4cbe68cefcf3/1e/temp_shuffle_57543b9a-3fe3-4692-9cf9-40d1f89b8455 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/disk11/yarn/nm/usercache/prodfinbatch01/appcache/application_1523529055210_30771/blockmgr-23238b36-41e7-4192-9af1-4cbe68cefcf3/1e/temp_shuffle_57543b9a-3fe3-4692-9cf9-40d1f89b8455 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.tHiveInput_1Process(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:2365)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.tAvroInput_1_InputFormatAvroProcess(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3718)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.run(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:4070)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.runJobInTOS(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3901)
    at project_cdl_tenant.job_cdl_010_sourcename_abcd_rawtoaccess_0_1.job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.main(job_CDL_010_sourcename_abcd_RawToAccess.java:3805)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.1 (TID 30301, dl200dn42.ddc.teliasonera.net): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

Comment: You're using YARN cluster manager and it looks like your executor got killed. You should have a look at the application logs using `yarn logs -applicationId`.

Comment: Yes Jacek, I saw this error in the Yarn log. ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 131.116.127.73:45245 disassociated! Shutting down. How can I remove this error?

Comment: Please provide the code and the command or configs you have used while executing the spark job.

Answer (score 1):

I could see that error message also contains

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/disk11/yarn/nm/usercache/prodfinbatch01/appcache/application_1523529055210_30771/blockmgr-23238b36-41e7-4192-9af1-4cbe68cefcf3/1e/temp_shuffle_57543b9a-3fe3-4692-9cf9-40d1f89b8455 (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

Check whether you're reading and writing into same path.

Or maybe due to block missing this could have happened.

Try rerunning.